# Predefine for Windows 8 || Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store, c++-cx

Is there a predefine when we are building for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 store applications, we need to detect which is selected so that we can disable some features.

I ask this because we're porting Windows 8.1 app to Windows 8. In Windows 8 some features are not available so we need to override them and implement something else. (Two projects, same code)

Comment: Was about to provide an answer but have to run so....start your journey with this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

Comment: Do you really want to have the behaviour depend on which OS you're using to compile the program?  Usually you would want it to depend on where you're *running* the program, or if you can't do the detection at run-time, you want to have two different builds.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have two builds but with shared source code. I needed to detect which features are available depending on which os i'm building for.

Comment: Yes, but why are you building on the OS you're building for?  That way you need multiple build machines instead of just one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think I don't understand what are you trying to say. I need to provide users with both W8 and W8.1 version of application because W8.1 has some more features that improve performance of the app. I can build both apps on one machine, they are in separated projects but with same source code.

Comment: Your question says that you want the build to depend on what operating system the compiler is running on.  From your last comment it's obvious that you didn't mean this, so please clarify your question: what *exactly* do you do differently when you want to build for 8.1?  You say you have a different project; what are the actual project settings that are different?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Have you ever made software for two different versions of API? The difference doesn't matter, I don't have trouble with that, I had trouble distinguishing between two compiler version for WinRT.

Comment: You didn't say you were compiling for WinRT!  In that case, I'll take your word for it that you use a different compiler depending on which WinRT version you're targeting, though that sounds very odd to me.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well I tagged Windows-Store... Windows RT 8 and Windows 8 are different OSs WinRT != Windows RT

Comment: My mistake, got confused there.  So you're building a "modern UI" app for Windows PCs, right?  Does that really require you to use a different compiler depending on the target version?

Comment: @HarryJohnston For example, in W8.1 there is component SwapChainPanel which can be set wherever and whatever size you want, you can even have multiple of them per page. In W8 there is only SwapChainBackgroundPanel which needs to be set full screen on page and can only be one per page. Here we would need to simulate separate containers for graphical presentation. And since we built our app around W8.1 features, some of them are not available in W8 version. It is easier to port few methods rather than rewrite and then have multiple components to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that - but that doesn't mean you need to use a different compiler!  For ordinary Win32 applications, at least, all you'd need to do is to define a macro in the build settings to tell your code whether to use the W8.1 components or not.  You use the same compiler, all that matters is that your code doesn't use any functions which aren't available in the target OS.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Oh, I thought that for W8.1 there was newer compiler then for W8 and VS automatically selected right one for each project. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `NTDDI_VERSION` macro.

```
#if NTDDI_VERSION == 0x06030000 // NTDDI_WINBLUE
    /* Windows 8.1 */
#elif NTDDI_VERSION == 0x06020000 // NTDDI_WIN8
    /* Windows 8 */
#endif
```

Make sure you've included `SdkDdkVer.h`, but it I believe most Windows projects already do that by default.

Comment: Hah, I totally forgot about Win versions :)

Comment: For conventional Windows applications, this is something that would normally be set in the source code itself.  Does Visual Studio set it for you when you're building modern UI applications?  How do you tell Visual Studio which OS you're targeting?